# Can my motherboard use this SSD?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, compatibility

I'm *very* new to the whole upgrade your PC thing, and I wanted to know if a particular SSD can fit my Motherboard, and if so/not, why.

SSD I want to upgrade to:
Intel 900P Optane NVMe PCIe 280GB

-Motherboard I have:
Asus PRIME H310-PLUS R2.0

Hope I haven't blundered anywhere, thanks for reading.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found about your motherboard, it does support the SSD as long as you don't have a GPU already in the PCIe x16 Slot.

Intel says it needs at least a PCIe x4 Slot ([Source](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/consumer-ssds/optane-ssd-9-series/optane-ssd-900p-series/900p-280gb-aic-20nm.html)) and your Motherboard only has one PCIe X16 Slot and one PCIe x1 Slot, the rest is PCI ([Source](https://www.asus.com/me-en/Motherboards/PRIME-H310-PLUS-R2-0/))

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I do have a gpu in there unfortunately. Is it possible to use a riser in 1 of the x1 slots to make it an x4? or is that too much of a graphical hit?

Comment: PCIe slots can't get upgraded like that. The x1, x4 etc is the amount of PCIe lanes connected to that slot. You can read more about PCIe lanes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Lane)